# Trying to intent.putExtra("timer", myTimer)?

Tags: kotlin

When I run this code I get the below error. Why? How to fix?

```
intent.putExtra("timer", myTimer)
```

> `None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied.`

Timer is this : https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer

Comment: passing a `Timer` around doesn't seem useful (nor possible) what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
 intent.putStringExtra("timer", myTimer.toString())
```

Comment: Then in destination you will convert this string to what you desire @Bandy